# jQuery Validation plugin - disable validation if certain condition met?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm using jQuery validator to validate certain `input` field. The user must enter something in that field, and `on select` I save that data somewhere. After the user has selected something from that `input` that field is cleared (but the data from that field exists). Is there any way to disable validation if initial data has been saved through that field?

HTML:

```
<form id="step3_cityForm">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled name="cityInput" id="cityInput" >
   </div>
</form>
```

Validator configuration:

```
$step3_cityValidator=$("#step3_cityForm").validate({
    rules:{
        cityInput:{
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, I ended up "cheating" and just created a dynamic `label` with the jQuery Validator `error` class, like this:

```
if(.. some condition..){
    var error=$('<label id="input-error" class="error" for="input">This field is required.</label>');
    $("#someDiv").append(error);
}
```

And this `label` is removed upon `input` field focus. Works like a charm to my needs.